# Jar files within a war archive have old changed date

Tags: java, maven, war

After upgrading the version of dependencies inside the pom.xml file, the version of the jar files inside the lib folder is getting upgraded, but the `changed date` of these files is somewhat old. In contrast, the war file was generated just moments before. Any idea why this is happening?
This is happening while the war file is generated on a date way ahead of this one.

[image: Example]

Comment: The jar file was created at that date, not when you built the war?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I also guess, but I couldn't find anything to be sure if it's the case. How come it puts the creation date as "changed date"?

Comment: How do you see this date?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen By executing `ll`

Comment: Did the unexpected jar dates cause a problem?  Do the jar all have the version number specified in the pom.xml?

Comment: Compare the date with the one of the artifact under .m2

Comment: @devdanke No problem is caused, and the version is correct. I'm just curious how the date of the content inside of an archive that is just generated fresh is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: Lib A depend on `foo-3.2.5.jar` . Your war depend on Lib A.

Case 2: Your other project B what created on Jan 1st 2022, depend on `foo-3.2.5.jar`

Your WAR depend on `foo-3.2.4.jar` , then you upgrade to `foo-3.2.5.jar` (it was exist)

If you want see something brand new, delete all in `.m2` directory. Clear maven cache https://www.baeldung.com/maven-clear-cache

Comment: If I get it right. You mean there were already some jar files (required by other projects) existed on the cache, and thus it puts the date it downloaded it to .m2 as the "changed date"? Is there any document or stuff to support this hypothesis?

Comment: Quite hard to find exist document. You can test/experiment by your self. Change your time of your PC.